# How can I use a Raspberry Pi as a router between two WiFi networks?

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, ssh-tunneling, rdesktop

I want to RDP from PC1 (Running Windows 7), to PC2 (Running Windows 7) using Pi (Raspberry Pi running Debian).

This the network situation:

```
               Network1                      Network2
      ---------------------------   ---------------------------
      |                         |   |                         |
      |        -------         -------        -------         |
      |        | PC1 | -----> |  Pi  | -----> | PC2 |         |
      |        -------         -------        -------         |
      |                         |   |                         |
      |                         |   |                         |
      |                         |   |                         |
      ---------------------------   ---------------------------
```

- PC1 is connected to Network1.
- PC2 is connected to Network2.
- Pi is connected to both networks.

On Pi:

- wlan0 is connected to Network1.
- wlan1 is connected to Network2.

I assume this is somehow possible, but I haven't done anything like this before so I'm pretty clueless.

Again, the question is how to set up the Pi as a router between the two?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up remote desktop between two Windows 7 computers? If so, this question shouldn't be here - it's an Unix & Linux site! Or are you asking how to set up the Pi as a router between the two? Which is fine here. Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: You should do port forwarding

Comment: The second option, I'm asking how to set up the Pi as a router between the two. I've edited the last sentence. Is this clear enough? If not, how can I clarify that I'm asking about the second option you have mentioned?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh port forwarding sounds exactly like what I need. I know how to port forward in the context of a router allowing inbound connections from the internet, how do I do it in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables - t nat -A PREROUTING  -p tcp -m tcp  --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.200:3389
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m state -d 192.168.1.200 --dport 3389 --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Suppose 192.168.1.200 is your windows.

Comment: 192.168.1.200 is the destination I want to RDP to (PC2)? And after I run this on PI, I simply RDP to the PI from PC1?

Comment: yes , you can change it.

Comment: Great, and how does it know to forward to the 192.168.1.200 on wlan1 and not wlan0? Because there is a 192.168.1.200 on both networks (in my case 10.0.0.1).

Comment: I get an error:
iptables v1.4.12: unknown option --dport

Comment: i edit my post , please again copy/paste

Comment: maybe you need UDP protocol please consider http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/5c7a18e9-caa0-41cc-b6a3-a52ced7be838/tcp-or-udp-3389?forum=winserverTS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17010/discussion-between-orny-and-mohsen-pahlevanzadeh).